# RecyclerView keeps repeating cached (?) subview and not looking to onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView where every list item has an ImageButton, thee image of which I define in the adapter's onBindViewHolder():

```
    int myVote = getMyVote();
    if (myVote != 0) {
        Log.d("dbg", myVote + "");
        holder.ratingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_grey600_36dp);
    }
```

So ratingButton is a star in the right bottom corner of the list item layout. Its shape is filled with gray color (and accordingly, a log record is pushed) if the condition (myVote != 0) is satisfied.

The problem is that when I scroll the list down I can watch other stars became filled even though I can see the only one record in the log window (for the correct list item). Moreover, this list items with incorrectly changed buttons repeat every 5 rows, and that's what's confusing me. If I change

```
mListView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
```

the repeat period changes to 3, so we can assume it somehow connected with the RecyclerView's caching and recycling mechanism.

Please, help me to work the problem out. Thanks!

Comment: You are showing the `if` block for the test `myVote != 0`. Please paste in your `else` block, where you are calling `setImageResource()` for the other value. And, if you do not have such an `else` block, that would be your problem.

Comment: Implement both getItemId() and getItemViewType() as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316837/how-to-prevent-items-from-getting-duplicated-when-scrolling-recycler-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your code to:

```
if (myVote != 0) {
        Log.d("dbg", myVote + "");
        holder.ratingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_grey600_36dp);
    } else {
        holder.ratingButton.setImageResource(int another resource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to implement

```
public long getItemId(int position) {}
```

otherwise, you'll see repeated items in *RecyclerView*.

Comment: getItemId implementation seems useless for this issue

Answer (score 2):

You may also have to write `else` part of main condition with `some another resource` like:

```
if (myVote != 0) {
    Log.d("dbg", myVote + "");
    holder.ratingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_grey600_36dp);
} else {
    holder.ratingButton.setImageResource(int another_resource);
}
```

It is worked for me.