# How to prevent same item keep repeating shown in RecycleView when pulling Swipe Refresh Layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` which inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout` which will get the `Post` JSON from my php server.

So the situation now is,I have only 5 `post`in my database.So when the first time I launch the `RecyclerView`,it shown the 5 `post`,this is no problem.

The main problem now is,every time I pull the `SwipeRefreshLayout` it pull the same 5 `post` to display in the `RecyclerView` again,therefore now is total 10 item inside the `RecyclerView`,and a particular same post appear 2 times.When I put again,it will appear once again,so total now 15 items each `post` appear 3 times.So this will appear infinity times.

I tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316837/how-to-prevent-items-from-getting-duplicated-when-scrolling-recycler-view) from this question which is Override the following 2 method but the same item still appear.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

So what I want is,if there are only 5 `posts` available in database,it just display 5 `posts` in the `RecyclerView`.When user pull the `SwipeRefreshLayout` it wont display out the 5 same `posts` one more time,but tell user no more any newer post.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: when you pull down you are adding items in your array list i guess, but before adding just check if item exists in array list , if array list already has item then don't add the item again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear the   `adpater` when the user pulls the `swiper` and reload the new data again to avoid repeating

try using this method to clear the data:

```
public void clear() {
        int size = this.myList.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                this.myList.remove(0);
            }

            this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }
```

Comment: bro this must be `remove(0)`,is this remove the 1st item in the adapter list?

Comment: cause now my list have 5 items,but it only shown 4 items in the RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

try to remove all items from array before reading the JSON